# Rails does not equal current_user always has no results

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am completely stumped. I'm trying to show objects that do not belong to the current user. Looks like this:

```
activities = Activity.where("user_id != ?", current_user.id)
@activities = activities.near(@user).all( :order => "start_date", :limit => 15)
```

But when I do this, no results are found, even though my database is full of objects where the user_id is NULL or someone else. The output looks fine as well to my rookie eyes. I can't figure out why nothing is getting pulled.

Output:

```
Activity Load (0.7ms)  SELECT activities.*, 3958.755864232 
* 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.7749295 - activities.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + 
COS(37.7749295 * PI() / 180) * COS(activities.latitude * PI() / 180) * 
POWER(SIN((-122.4194155 - activities.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) AS distance, 
CAST(DEGREES(ATAN2( RADIANS(activities.longitude - -122.4194155), 
RADIANS(activities.latitude - 37.7749295))) + 360 AS decimal) % 360 AS bearing FROM 
"activities" WHERE (user_id != 34) AND (activities.latitude BETWEEN 37.4854659337783 AND 
38.0643930662217 AND activities.longitude BETWEEN -122.78562893449197 AND 
-122.05320206550803 AND 3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((37.7749295 - 
activities.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(37.7749295 * PI() / 180) * 
COS(activities.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-122.4194155 - activities.longitude) * 
PI() / 180 / 2), 2))) <= 20) ORDER BY start_date, distance ASC LIMIT 15
```

If I try the query:

```
activities = Activity.where('user_id IS ?', nil)
```

I get the expected objects. Why do I get no results trying to not equal current_user.id?

Also, I've tried different permutations like where.not(user_id: current_user.id), <> ?, and a few others. And the results are the same.

**UPDATED**

I ended up making user_id's default value "1" rather than NULL. Once I did that, the code above worked fine. I guess my failing is not understanding the properties of nil(?)

Comment: Did you accidently make user_id a string field?

Comment: It's an integer field, but I had the same thought.

Comment: Can you reproduce without the second line - ie without all the `near` stuff? In other words, is the issue in the the `user_id !=` part or in the whole latitude/longitude search part.

Comment: Yes, I can. All the near stuff works fine. I can, for instance, swap out the user_id stuff for .where(start_date IS NOT NULL) for instance, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
activities = Activity.where("user_id <> ?", current_user.id)
```

or (Rails 4)

```
activities = Activity.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)
```

And (Rails 3)

```
activities = Activity.where(Activity.arel_table[:user_id].not_eq(current_user.id)
```

... ish

Comment: Yes, I've tried your options 1 and 2 (I'm on Rails 4). That's why I'm so confused. Any other ideas of what the problem could be?

Comment: Without knowing more about the schema/relationships/attributes it's a little difficult to diagnose. Have you just tried opening up the rails console and manually typing your ruby where clauses? `rails c`. What I mean is, you can run `Activity.where.not(user_id: current_user.id)` in the console too. Try queries that way. It's much faster and you're more likely to come across any silly mistakes.

Comment: try the where part in your console also see what u get in ur current_user object and see what sql query is generated when u try this Activity.where("user_id != ?", current_user.id).to_sql

Comment: You can see my edit above. I ended up using a user_id of 1 in my Activity table. That made the code work. So it's some problem with NULL? I'm still confused.